# How to recover deleted machines from MAAS

Tags: maas

I was deleting a test machine from maas (nodes -> machines) and accidentally delete several other machines.  They were rediscovered several minutes later but now are in the devices (nodes -> devices)

What is the procedure to get them back as machines again?

Comment: @9291Sam so? MAAS is perfectly on topic here.

Comment: @grooveplex what are you Talking about ?

Comment: Also how did you know I was on this question

Comment: @9291Sam I replied to you before you removed your comment :)